# Prove that if MST T1 has k edges with weight 1 then T2 has also k edges with weight 1

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, proof-explanation, trees

We have two different minimum spanning trees ($T_1$ and $T_2$) of $G$. The graph $G$ has edges with weight $1$ or $2$. How can I prove that if $T_1$ has $k$ edges with weight equal to $1$ then $T_2$ has also $k$ edges with weight equal to $1$?

Comment: Are there negative or zero weight edges?

Comment: Sorry i edit my question. The graph has edges with weight 1 or 2.

Comment: The two trees have the same number of vertices, hence the same number of edges altogether. And they have the same weight. Can you relate the weight to the number of edges of weight $1$?

Comment: Do you know the proof of Kruskal's algorithm? A similar argument will work here by considering the first point at which a different edge is selected in the construction of a minimum spanning tree (for something quicker and more to-the-point, I think you'll prefer @DanielFischer's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ denote the number of vertices in $G$. Let $k_1$ be the number of edges with weight one in $T_1$. Then the total weight of $T_1$ is $k_1 + 2(n - k_1)$. Similarly, the total weight of $T_2$ is $k_2 + 2(n - k_2)$ where $k_2$ denotes the number of edges with weight one in $T_2$. Since both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are minimum spanning trees we must have $k_1 + 2(n - k_1) = k_2 + 2(n - k_2)$. After cancelling out some terms we get $-k_1 = -k_2$ and hence $k_1 = k_2$.